# laravel 4 get a JSON value for a given key

Tags: php, json, laravel-4

I'm using:

```
$location = file_get_contents($mapurl);
```

which responds with json:

```
{
  "results" : [],
  "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

**how can I extract a value for a given key ?**

I've tried:

```
$status = $location::get('status');
```

but this is throwing errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$location = json_decode(file_get_contents($mapurl));
$status = $location->status;
```

`file_get_contents` returns a string, you have to call `json_decode` convert it to an object then you can access the status property.